# Do type conversions in Java also cause a conversion in the memory bytes?

Tags: java

If I convert an `int` to a `double` by doing this:

```
int x = 5; 
double y = x;
```

I know that `y` will be having a value of `5.0`, but when `x` variable is set to the `double y` variable, which is being converted by automatic type conversion in Java, is the amount of bytes in memory also converted indirectly automatically by Java for us?

An `int` is 4 bytes while a `double` is 8 bytes, so in this case the value coming from variable `x` when setting the value for variable `y`, will be converted indirectly memory bytes wise by the language? I guess this memory conversion would hold the same if I did casting or used some sort of method to convert the data types instead of automatic type conversion?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but I think you have problem here:

> If I convert an int to a double by doing this: int x = 5; double y = x;

You are not *converting* from an `int` to a `double`. You are creating a `double` from an `int` value. Which also means that there is allocated memory for `double` value and the original `int` is left intact.

See the following example:

```
@Test
void testPrimitive() {
    int x = 5;
    double y = x;
    log.info("x:{}", x);
    log.info("y:{}", y);
    x += 1;
    log.info("x:{}", x);
    log.info("y:{}", y);
    // This is the way to assign a value double to an int:
    // You need to cast so strip the decimal part explicitly! 
    // This changes the value of int but does not alter bytes or so just drops bytes
    x = (int)y;
    y += 5;
    log.info("x:{}", x);
    log.info("y:{}", y);        
}
```

and what it prints out:

> 11:16:11.368 [main] INFO org.example.type.PrimitiveTest - x:5
> 11:16:11.373 [main] INFO org.example.type.PrimitiveTest - y:5.0
> 11:16:11.375 [main] INFO org.example.type.PrimitiveTest - x:6
> 11:16:11.375 [main] INFO org.example.type.PrimitiveTest - y:5.0
> 11:16:11.375 [main] INFO org.example.type.PrimitiveTest - x:5
> 11:16:11.375 [main] INFO org.example.type.PrimitiveTest - y:10.0

**x** & **y** are having their own memory spaces and you are not altering the amount of their bytes not even with casting.